# Google calendar API authentication HttpError - used to work but no longer does

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have a python script that I use to create google calendar events for my shifts at work as I am sent these in an excel file 3-6 monthly.

This script used to work fine (6 months ago when I last used it), when I try it now I get the following error despite refreshing my credentials.json file and clearing my token.json:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

If I use the same authentication script, scopes and credentials using the google calender API [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) example, it successfully accesses and prints my upcoming events.

I don't understand why it is failing to authenticate to create the events, but managing to read, with appropriate scopes, or why this used to work but no longer does.

Here is the python script (calendarID annonymised):

```
# Import libs
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials


# USER VARIABLES
name = 'Name'
date = 'Date'
location = 'Hospital address'
rota_file = 'rota.xlsx'
calendarID = '<calendarID>@group.calendar.google.com'

# DEFINE SHIFT TYPES
LD = {'alias': 'LD', 'name': 'Long'}
ND = {'alias': 'ND', 'name': 'Short'}
NI = {'alias': 'NI', 'name': 'Night'}
IND = {'alias': 'IND', 'name': 'Induction'}


# List of dicts for shift types
shift_list = [LD, ND, NI, IND]

# Read rota file and parse dates
rota = pd.read_excel(rota_file, parse_dates=True)

# Initialize empty dict for dict of shift dates
shift_dates = {}

# Create dict with key as shift name and value as list of dates when this
# shift occurs
for shift in shift_list:
    shift_dates[shift['name']] = rota[date][rota[name].str.fullmatch(
        shift['alias'], na=False)].astype(str).tolist()

# CREATE AND AUTHENTICATE GOOGLE CALENDAR API SERVICE
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

# Builds service
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)


# CREATE EVENTS IN GOOGLE CALENDAR
# Create shift event for each date in a series of datetime dates
def create_shifts(dates, shift):
    event = {
        'summary': shift,
        'location': location,
        'start': {
            'date': dates,
            'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
        },
        'end': {
            'date': dates,
            'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
        },
    }

    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendarID, body=event).execute()
    print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))


# tuple unpack the dict of shifts and dates and iterate through creating shifts
for shift, dates in shift_dates.items():
    for date in dates:
        create_shifts(date, shift)
```

And the full error print out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/mark/OneDrive/py/rota/rota.py", line 89, in <module>
    create_shifts(date, shift)
  File "/Users/mark/OneDrive/py/rota/rota.py", line 82, in create_shifts
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendarID, body=event).execute()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 937, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calenderID>40%40group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">
```

I'm a real amateur when it comes to coding and have been trying to solve this myself but am really stuck. This was till now one of the most useful projects I'd set myself to improve. Any help anyone can offer would be really apprectiated!